# Why I can't send message to kafka through AsyncLogger/AsyncAppender with FailoverAppender?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to write a demo to test **asynclog** but I realized **it didn't work sending a message to kafka**. Wha should I do to make it work ?  code will paste in behind.
 
**add: this situation should tell you.** when I added a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in my async test main class today and **it works** but won't trigger failover  ref appender ,whatever I set kafka syncSend to true/false it didn't work.
 
Here are some other problems I want to ask for:)

1. if i use async to send log to kafka as **audit logging framework** could it 
   **guarantee reliability**? 
   Because in here [log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) it says  
   "recommend to synchronously log those audit messages."
2. In **sync** situation I've use a **failoverappender** to save lose messages in 
   local disk file.But may i have a better way to resend these messages to 
   kafka?did it work in async situation?
   Because now i can't delete the file and i use the filebeat to scan 
   the file and send to logstash.
3. I've made a Util to Packaging interface of log4j2,and in this way it can't get right location message in log4j2.xml PatternLayout like "%C %M %F %L",and i then use 
   `"Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];"`
   in my util class to get these message (Internally called other methods so the index was 3) and splice String to send log message like this:
   `"logger.error(MarkerManager.getMarker("MESSAGE"),"Class: {}   Method: {} File: {}  Line: {} ---{}",X,X,X,X,JSON.toJSONString(X));"`
   May I've a better way to optimization these code and get these location information?

I test on windows OS, I'm using java language, spring boot project.
Here there are some base pom dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<configuration status="debug" monitorInterval="10">
    <properties>
        <property name="LOG_HOME">logs/TESTPROJECT</property>
        <property name="PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE">%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level --- %msg %xEx%n</property>
        <property name="PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE_ROOT">%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level --- Class: %C Method: %M File: %F Line:
            %L --- %msg %xEx%n
        </property>
        <property name="PATTERN_LAYOUT">%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level --- %msg %xEx%n</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8">
                <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE_ROOT}">
                    <PatternMatch key="UTIL" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="MESSAGE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE}"/>
                </MarkerPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFileInfo" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/info.log"
                                 filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/info/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"
                                 bufferSize="4096" immediateFlush="false" bufferedIO="true" append="true">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8">
                <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE_ROOT}">
                    <PatternMatch key="UTIL" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="MESSAGE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                </MarkerPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0/12 * * ?"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50">
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_HOME}" testMode="true" maxDepth="5">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*/info/info-*.log.gz">
                        <IfLastModified age="180d">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="50GB"/>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="1000"/>
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfLastModified>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFileWarn" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/warn.log"
                                 filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/warn/warn-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"
                                 bufferSize="4096" immediateFlush="false" bufferedIO="true" append="true">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8">
                <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE_ROOT}">
                    <PatternMatch key="UTIL" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="MESSAGE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                </MarkerPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0/12 * * ?"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50">
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_HOME}" testMode="true" maxDepth="5">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*/warn/warn*.log.gz">
                        <IfLastModified age="180d">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="50GB"/>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="1000"/>
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfLastModified>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFileError" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/error.log"
                                 filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/error/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"
                                 append="true">
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8">
                <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT_CONSOLE_ROOT}">
                    <PatternMatch key="UTIL" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="TRACE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                    <PatternMatch key="MESSAGE" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
                </MarkerPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0/12 * * ?"/>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50">
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_HOME}" testMode="true" maxDepth="5">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/*/error/error*.log.gz">
                        <IfLastModified age="180d">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="50GB"/>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="1000"/>
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfLastModified>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <Kafka name="KafkaSync" topic="yi-test" syncSend="false" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <MarkerFilter marker="MESSAGE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">192.100.2.44:9092,192.100.2.45:9092</Property>
            <Property name="timeout.ms">3000</Property>
            <Property name="max.block.ms">2000</Property>
        </Kafka>
        <Kafka name="KafkaTrace" topic="yi-test2" syncSend="false" ignoreExceptions="false">
            <MarkerFilter marker="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR"/>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">192.100.2.44:9092,192.100.2.45:9092</Property>
            <Property name="timeout.ms">3000</Property>
            <Property name="max.block.ms">2000</Property>
        </Kafka>
        <File name="failoverKafkaLog" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/failover.log"
              ignoreExceptions="false">
            <MarkerFilter marker="MESSAGE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
        </File>
        <File name="failoverKafkaTraceLog" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/failoverTrace.log"
              ignoreExceptions="false">
            <MarkerFilter marker="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout charset="utf-8" pattern="${PATTERN_LAYOUT}"/>
        </File>
        <Failover name="Failover" primary="KafkaSync" retryIntervalSeconds="15">
            <Failovers>
                <appender-ref ref="failoverKafkaLog"/>
            </Failovers>
        </Failover>
        <Failover name="FailoverTrace" primary="KafkaTrace" retryIntervalSeconds="15">
            <Failovers>
                <appender-ref ref="failoverKafkaTraceLog"/>
            </Failovers>
        </Failover>
        <Async name="AsyncKafka">
            <appender-ref ref="Failover"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FailoverTrace"/>
        </Async>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.logtest.demo" level="debug" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <!--i have tried all these ref situations and no one work -->
            <appender-ref ref="Failover"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FailoverTrace"/>
            <!--<appender-ref ref="KafkaSync"/>-->
            <!--<appender-ref ref="KafkaTrace"/>-->
            <!--<appender-ref ref="AsyncKafka"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="RollingRandomAccessFileInfo"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingRandomAccessFileWarn"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingRandomAccessFileError"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <root level="info" includeLocation="true">
            <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        </root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/> <!-- avoid recursive logging -->
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Here is the log when I run test class and set log4j2 configuration level to debug :
the log file i push to my github [mygithub](https://github.com/lMasterSparkl/lgo4j2asynctestlog/blob/master/log4j2.log)
because my it limited the body limited :(